# Right Way to Secure MSMQ over HTTP

Tags: iis, iis-7, msmq

We're in the middle of migrating an e-commerce integration from using batching to messaging (MSMQ). The e-commerce application itself is hosted on a web server that is not in our domain. The machine processing orders is in the domain in our LAN. The e-commerce app will write to a local MSMQ when an order is placed. Our order processing component should connect to this queue and read messages from it. We are not using WCF for this.

If it were up to me I'd either ditch MSMQ and go with RabbitMQ or put a vpn client on both machines like Hamachi.

I know that MSMQ can use HTTP as a transport via IIS. However I can't seem to find much documentation on how to set this up securely. Is it as simple as turning on one of the authentication options in IIS? I would prefer to use basic auth as we plan on doing this over HTTPS. After that, how to send credentials from the order processing component?

Answer (score 0):

MSMQ supports HTTP and HTTPS. For details, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785272(v=ws.10).aspx
Cheers,
Yoel